# using variable in prepend img src

Tags: jquery, variables, prepend

I have a img source I'm trying to prepend but I'm trying to use the variable "id" in the source.  I'm having trouble modifying this snippet of code to do that.

```
  $('#photo_850').prepend('<img src= id + ".jpg" />');
```

thanks for helping me with this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your concatenation was off:

```
$('#photo_850').prepend('<img src="'+id+'.jpg" />');
```

Another, perhaps easier to read, method would be:

```
$("<img>", { src: id + ".jpg" }).prependTo("#photo_850");
```

This method first creates the element represented by a string in the first parameter. Next, jQuery proceeds to map the members of the object literal to the newly-created HTML element. You can probably guess by now that our newly-created `<img>` will have a `src` property of `foo.jpg`, assuming the variable `id` is a string of `"foo"`.

Comment: I wish I understood what was going on in the second method...looks interesting

Comment: thanks for the answer, I actually wouldn't mind an explanation for that second method either.

Comment: Does this apply to other elements? say $('<input>', {type: 'text'}) ? And should this only be used to create an element to prepend, append and so on?

Comment: @VIDesignz Try it ;) Use it however you like. It's a quick and easy way to create an HTMLElement and quickly drop it into the DOM (or not).

Comment: I will definitely be experimenting with it, and thanks for hooking me up with this approach!